# Does the twitter oAuth API tell you if the account is verified?

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have users who login via the Twitter API and want to see if the users have been verified with the blue checkmark.

[image]

Is this data exposed?  How can I get access to this value?  I'm using C# but this question really relates to REST

Comment: Verified in the sense? Verified account or the account is verified through email or not? & pl mention what Library and language you are using.

Comment: @YuvaRaj C# , and clarified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed your question is related to the REST API and not to the platform. The field you are looking for is called "verified". You can get it for a user request, e.g. [GET users show](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show).

A full description of the object *user* can be found [here](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes - https://support.twitter.com/articles/119135-faqs-about-verified-accounts  Thanks!